# how to download a PDF file with public URL?

Tags: pdf, community-cloud

I have created a accordion in lightning component  where I want to display a link to download a pdf file publicly(that exists in database) for anyone visiting the community. I am querying ContentDistribution to get the URL. Can someone help me on how to proceed at the client side?
   Thanks in advance for your help.

Lightning Component:

```
 <aura:attribute name="Formation" type="Formation__c[]"/>
 <aura:attribute name="Mod" type="Module__c[]"/> 
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
 <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion"> 
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.Formation}" var="Formation"> 
    <lightning:accordionSection label="{!Formation.Name}"> <aura:set attribute="body"> 
    <aura:iteration items="{!Formation.Modules__r}" var="Mod"> 
    <div class="slds-text" >{!Mod.Name}</div> 
    //download link <a href="{!'communityname/sfc/p' + {!Mod.url__c}}" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD </a>
```

Lightning Controller:

```
doInit: function(component,event,helper){ 
    var action = component.get("c.getFormation"); 
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") 
        component.set("v.Formation", response.getReturnValue()); 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class training {  
    @AuraEnabled Public 
    Static List<Formation__c> getFormation(){
        return [Select Name, (select Name, Image__c, Duree__c, Description__c, URL__c from IAModules__r) from Formation__c]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is issue...you should be able to query DistributionPublicUrl from ContentDistribution and use that. ..

Comment: Thanks for you rreply Ayub. Yes I am able to query the link both DistributionPublicUrl  and ContentDownloadUrl but I am unable to pass it in the <a href> or a button so that when a user clicks on it they are able to download it. Can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: Can you please add your code, query and result...it would help to solve the issue quickly.

Comment: Sorry Medhavi...still it's not clear about "URL__c" field...how do we what is this...is this a URL? If yes...then what is possible value ...how do you populate it.....because it's important to know source of file....to open it..

Comment: I believe the issue here was that the content in the salesforce org are shared from different instance(--documentforce.com) & the code uses relative url. You need to have complete url in the relative & it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please upload that PDF file in documents

1. In the Sites Profile ("public access settings"), enable Read access to Documents (You indicate that this is already the case)
2. Edit the folder in which the document is stored, and ensure that the Sites profile has access to the folder. To do this, I went to Admin setup ---> Manage Users ---> Public Groups and created a group consisting of ONLY the User defined by my Sites profile. You can then add this "group" to the permissions on the folder.

Use  and in the value put "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=(your docs ID here)"

Comment: Hi Sagar,
"/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=(your docs ID here)" this link does not allow pulic sharining. I have attached teh document in a files related list of the custom object and created a public sharing url field. Can you please tell me how can pass the url from the field in <a href> ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this url='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=id'

Make sure that id you passed in the tag should correct. Open the download file and then copy the URL and ID from the browser then paste it in your code to verify.

you can refer this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_example_linking_to_documents.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Deepak.
I tried using the link you have shared but this way I am unable to give public access.
I am not getting an id of the file but I am getting an entire link from the database which is like "https://MyPublicCommunityNAME/sfc/dist/version/download/?oid=00D6E0000008orm&ids=0686E000000PbTs&d=%2Fa%2F6E00000006qx%2F6BbDGAHdFPRYpyw_1G0CXg1sOepu3F__chItxPDRP98&asPdf=false"
I am storing this link in a field in the object but I am unable to pass it to a button or a <a href>. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below URL -

https:///sfc/dist/version/download/?oid=&ids=&d=&operationContext=DELIVERY

example : https://buk--myorg--c.cs80.content.force.com/sfc/dist/version/download/?oid=00D250000009DOu&ids=06825000000rc3vAZS&d=/a/25000000ESKv/cf0wNvhycdsfY8uRIzWfMmDV5AzyerHGVypbKyIEp3Prw&operationContext=DELIVERY

**HTML Code :** -

```
<a id="pdfDownloadNew11" href="https://buk--myorg--c.cs80.content.force.com/sfc/dist/version/download/?oid=00D250000009DOu&ids=06825000000rc3vAZS&d=/a/25000000ESKv/cf0wNvhycdsfY8uRIzWfMmDV5AzyerHGVypbKyIEp3Prw&operationContext=DELIVERY" shouldstayinownframe="true" title="Download Statement"><button class="slds-button slds-button_stretch bdl-button_small" type="button" id="moiDownloadACopy11">Download</button></a>
```