# how to retrive /fire a link from a cutom object field

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller

I am storing the public url of a pdf file in a field of a custom object. I am able to successfully retrieve the url.
how can I fire the url when a user click a button? Is it possible through JS controller?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is that lightning component?

Comment: yes. I tried doing it in href tag 
<a href="{!Module.URL__c}" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD </a> 
but this  does not work.
Module is the nale of the custom object and URL__C is the field name.

Comment: How is this post any different than [your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241640/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-public-url)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **e.force:navigateToURL**,

on press of a button fire the below event, it will open that URL

```
gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": 'fileURL';
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pranay. 
It is wrking when I am assigning a static url but how do I pass the url dynamically in this function? My url is stored in URL__c field of a custom object which I am retrieving in the APEX class.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Follow this, this will tell u how to get that URL from APex, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

Once you got the URL you can redirect